# Mysql insert into two tables at same time

Tags: php, mysql

I need to save content into two tables. I have this code, but it save just into table games. I need save into the games all content and into archive just id, title and date of article.

Any help?

Thanks very much

```
 <?php
include("../includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$games_date = date('y-m-d-h');
$games_title = $_POST['title'];
$games_author = $_POST['author'];
$games_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$games_link = $_POST['download_link'];
$games_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$games_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$games_content = $_POST['content'];

if($games_title=="" or $games_author=="" or $games_keywords=="" or $games_content=="" or $games_download_link="")
{
    echo"<script>alert('any field is empty')</script>";
    exit();
}
else 
{
move_uploaded_file($games_tmp,"../uploaded_images/$games_image");
$games_query = "insert into games (games_title,games_date,games_author,games_image,games_keywords,games_link,games_content) values ('$games_title','$games_date','$games_author','$games_image','$games_keywords','$games_link','$games_content')";
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
$archive_query = "insert into archive (title, pub_date) values ('$games_title','$games_date',)";
}
   if(mysqli_query($connect,$games_query))
{
    echo "<center><h1>Post published seccesfuly!</h1></center>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I only see that you are running the `$games_query` and not the `$archive_query`.  Are you missing some of the code?

Comment: No that's all from this script. I think that i was missing something what but i don't know is it.

Comment: You are not executing the `$archive_query`. It's not going to jump up and magically execute itself. Your code is also vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), making it potentially possible for someone to corrupt your database, steal information from it, or take control of the site.

Comment: yes i know that isn't safe...now i just need to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`mysqli::multi_query`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

```
$query  = "insert into games (games_title,games_date,games_author,games_image,games_keywords,games_link,games_content) values ('$games_title','$games_date','$games_author','$games_image','$games_keywords','$games_link','$games_content');";
$query .= "insert into archive (title, pub_date) values ('$games_title','$games_date')";

if (mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) {

    echo "Data in two tables successfully inserted.";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? Also, did you check out the manual link I gave you ?

Comment: there is no error...it will show Post published seccesfuly and all content is in games. Yes i checked

Comment: Did it print `Data in two tables successfully inserted.` ?

Comment: ou...you mean your solution...there is error: Fatal error: Call to a member function mutli_query() on a non-object in line 76 (if($mysqli->mutli_query($games_query))
 {
  echo "<center><h1>Post published seccesfuly!</h1></center>";
 }
}

Comment: @psajtik, Sorry .. can you try now ? I have changed the `if` condition.

Comment: There is no way you will get the same error.. Please try my new code.. or paste in this site https://eval.in and send me the link.

Comment: https://eval.in/124906 , Copy the code and try substituting the localhost values and check this example.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you have any problems let me know. Happy coding !

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that you need to insert the **id**, I'd prefer to go with this way

```
....
if(mysqli_query($connect,$games_query)){
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
    $archive_query = "insert into archive (id, title, pub_date) values ('$last_id', '$games_title','$games_date')";
    mysqli_query($connect,$archive_query); // execute the archive query here
    echo "<center><h1>Post published seccesfuly!</h1></center>";
  }
}
```